# Checkbox OnCheckedChanged not firing when checkbox is checked through JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I used this code to be able to check the checkbox on gridview row select which is working. However, the code behind is not being run unless I click the actual checkbox. Any ideas?

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvReconciledGroups" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Reconciled Items to Batch" DataKeyNames="GroupID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbFinalise" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbFinalise_OnCheckedChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="GroupID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataField="GroupID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cashier" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataField="Cashier" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('tr.gridview_row,tr.gridview_alternatingRow').click(function () {
            var checked = $(this).find('input[id*=cbFinalise]').prop('checked');
            $(this).find('input[id*=cbFinalise]').prop('checked', !checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
public void cbFinalise_OnCheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Calculations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is entirely client side. `OnCheckedChanged` will only fire on the server side after a postback has happened due to the radio `input` being clicked on. Try this:

```
$('tr.gridview_row,tr.gridview_alternatingRow').click(function () {
    $(this).find('input[id*=cbFinalise]').click(); // this should force a postback
});
```

Note that manually changing the `checked` property of the control is redundant as you will be refreshing the page anyway and the state of the control will be set by ASP.Net as it re-renders the page.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to trigger a click on your checkbox in order to force the postback :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $('tr.gridview_row,tr.gridview_alternatingRow').click(function () {
           $(this).find('input[id*=cbFinalise]').trigger('click');
       });
   });
</script>
```